# Sending sms message using uni- rest in Net bean

Tags: java, android, api, unirest

I am trying to send sms message message in java using uni-rest .I am encountering some error .when i enter phone number error is shown of NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity and some few more errors that  I think issue is with jar files ? 
Below is the code i have written to send sms using uni-rest and all the libraries are attached in snip shot and also error snapshot is attached .It seems like jar file is not getting added with project . What i am doing wrong ?

```
public class JavaApplication2 {


    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnirestException, IOException {
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your phone number: ");
        String phoneNumber = scanIn.nextLine();
        scanIn.close();
                System.out.printf("entering to http response is ");

    /*HttpResponse<String> response =                       
    Unirest.post("xyz")
    .header("authorization", "abc")
    .header("content-type", "application/json")
    .header("accept", "application/json")
    .body("[{"
                + "'from': 'Example',"
                + "'to': '" +"435456"+ "',"
                + "'body': 'Hello World. This is a test message',"
                + "}]")
          .asString();
      */

          HttpResponse<String> response 
         =Unirest.post("http://xyz")
         .header("authorization", "abc")
         .header("content-type", "application/json")
         .header("accept", "application/json")


     .body({\"from\":\"InfoSMS\",\"to\":\"45465678\",\"text\":\"TestSMS.\"}")
         .asString(
         );



        }
    }
```

**I have  used following libraries**
[image]

**I am getting following  error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the required jars(containing httpEntity and other relevant class ) to your `classpath` while running your program. Build path is used for compiling /building your code but not for execution.

Comment: Thanks for response .i have already added all the libraries required .can you tell me what libraries else should i add ?

Comment: You need to add the required jars(containing httpEntity and other relevant class ) to your `classpath` while running your program. Build path is used for compiling /building your code but not for execution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue . Actually  NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity  was because i have not included "org.json.jar" library due to which errors were showing . After adding the "org.json.jar" in my library . All the errors are gone and sending sms is also working fine.